# applying formula in the column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula looking for the column "NAME", adding a blank column after it and naming this new column "word count". Now I need to apply following formula in the new column:

`=TRIM(LEN(E2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E2," ","")))+1`

Column E is the "NAME" column; however, the location of this column might change from file to file.

Comment: It should be good to show us the code "looking for the column 'NAME"... Do you mean "C" for column "C:C"? Now, I suppose that you do not want to apply the above formula on the whole column. So, based on which column to calculate the last row where the formula to be applied? If you are able to define the range, the formula can be applied without any iteration...

Comment: Each file has a column "name", it could be column A or any other column in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It searches for the column header "NAME". **in the first row of the active sheet** and place the formula referencing the found column, in the second column after the found one:

```
Sub ApplyFormula()
   Dim strColName As String, colRng As Range, lastR As Long, colLetter As String
   strColName = "NAME" 'the header to search for
   'Supposing that the columns headers are in the first row:
    Set colRng = ActiveSheet.rows(1).Find(what:=strColName, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
   If Not colRng Is Nothing Then
        colLetter = Split(colRng.Address, "$")(1)
        lastR = cells(rows.count, colRng.Column).End(xlUp).row
        Range(colRng.Offset(1, 2), cells(lastR, colRng.Column + 2)).Formula = _
                       "=TRIM(LEN(" & colLetter & "2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & colLetter & lastR & ","" "","""")))+1"
    Else
        MsgBox "No """ & strColName & """ in the first row..." & vbCrLf & _
                   "Please, change the row (in the code) or search an existing header.", vbInformation, _
                   "No such column header..."
   End If
End Sub
```